# Issue with Python Multiple Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have two python base classes in which they request data from two servers with different arguments. There are two derived classes that inherit from these base classes and override data request. Since the base classes do not provide data management, they also add a data management function, which is exactly the same for both of the derived classes.

```
class Base1():
    def request_data_base1(self, argument1, argument2):
        # Needs to be overridden by the derived class
        pass
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Base2():
    def request_data_base2(self, different_argument1, different_argument2, different_argument3):
        # Needs to be overridden by the derived class
        pass
```

The derived classes:

```
class Derived1(Base1):
    # Derived1 inherits request_data from Base1, which is overridden here some new functionality
    def request_data_base1(self, argument1, argument2):
        # ...
        return
    
    # This method requests data and perform a data management
    def manage_data(self):
        # Using a method in Base1 request data
        self.request_data_base1(argument1, argument2)
        # perform data management
        # ...
        return
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Derived2(Base2):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    # Derived2 inherits request_data from Base2, which is overridden here some new functionality
    # request_data_base2 is different from request_data_base1
    def request_data_base2(self, different_argument1, different_argument2, different_argument3):
        # connect to server and request data
        return
    
    def manage_data(self):
        self.request_data_base2(different_argument1, different_argument2, different_argument3)
        # perform data management
        # data management which is exactly the same as the data management that happens in Derived1
        # ...
        return
```

In both `Derived1` and `Derived2` classes, the method `manage_data`:

- requesta data at a timely manner
- performs data management after the data is received

Requesting data in `Derived1` and `Derived2` are different (because `Base1` and `Base2` requires different arguments), **but the data management functions are exactly the same**. In fact, the nature of the data request is also the same between the two derived classes, but they require different arguments.

I would like to bring this data management outside of `Derived1` and `Derived2` by creating a third base class `Base3` which can be inherited by Derived1 and Derived2 for the data management functionality.

How can I design a third base class for this purpose? I was thinking of the following.

```
class Base3():
    # ...
    def request_data(self):
        # ...
        return
        
    def manage_data(self):
        # Do all the data management functionality
        return
```

which would make the derived classes as follows:

```
class Derived1(Base1, Base3):
    def request_data_base1(self, argument1, argument2):
        # connect to server and request data
        return
    
    # manage_data is inheritted form Base3
    
class Derived2(Base2, Base3):
    def request_data_base2(self, different_argument1, different_argument2, different_argument3):
        # connect to server and request data
        return
    
    # manage_data is inheritted form Base3
```

**Question:**

How should I bring the data management inside a separate class such that `Derived1` and `Derived2` only override the `request_data` functions and inherits `manage_data` from `Base3`?

Comment: I'm not quite following what you want to achieve. Since ``Base3`` exists only to ``request_data``, not to ``manage_data``, why does it have a ``manage_data`` method?

Comment: My goal is to eliminate `manage_data` from the derived classes. In fact, I want `manage_data` to be totally inherited from `Base3` such that `Derived1` and `Derived2` don't need to worry about data management, if this makes sense.